# Assigning function pointer with a dummy function in vector cast

Tags: vectorcast

The new function I created is not populated in vector cast's parameter tree.

I have a parameter in C code, to which I have to assign a function pointer, to do this I tried adding a dummy function in environment->user code->edit->unit appendix user code-> added a simple function under the file I needed it in like:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void vcast_dummy_function(uint64_t param_1, uint64_t param_2);


void vcast_dummy_function(uint64_t param_1, uint64_t param_2)
{
    /** Do some operation on input parameters and exit the code flow*/
    exit(0);
}
```

after adding this, I save and linked my code, and rebuild the enviroment.

But now this function is not visible in parameter tree.